# Can TypeScript possible to infer one generic argument from another?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a generic method with two type arguments, one of which is also generic:

```
function foo <T extends Entity<TEvents>, TEvents extends Record<string, any>>(): void { }
```

As you see the second argument is used as a generic argument of the first. It has to be called as

```
type Events = {}
interface MyEntity extends Entity<Events> {
}

foo<MyEntity, Events>(/* ... */)
```

Is it possible to type this method so that the second argument is not necessary? After all it seems that it could be inferred from type arguments of `MyEntity`...

In other words, I would like to simply call `foo<MyEntity>`. Currently I get an error `TS2558: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.`

Comment: What's `Entity`?  Also, could you give your example types some distinguishing properties [so the compiler can tell them apart?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  Basically it would be nice to have a true [mcve] so that all answers will have a good place from which to start. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript actually infers it without any explicit specification:
[image]

But if you insist on specifying something, you could reverse it like so:

```js
function foo<TEvents extends Record<string, any>, T extends Entity<TEvents> = Entity<TEvents>>(): void { } // note the default type

type Events = {};
interface MyEntity extends Entity<Events> {
}

foo<Events>(); // inferred as: function foo<Events, Entity<Events>>(): void
```

or

```js
function foo<T extends Entity<TEvents>, TEvents extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>>(): void { } // note the default type

type Events = {};
interface MyEntity extends Entity<Events> {
}

foo<MyEntity>(); // inferred as: function foo<MyEntity, Record<string, any>>(): void
```